# How to time SPARQL queries on an Oracle12c database?

Tags: oracle-12c, performance, performance-testing

I have an Oracle 12c instance setup with an Apache Fuseki endpoint sitting on top of it. I am able to query the database using the Fuseki endpoint. I want to be able to get the execution time of some queries without the network overhead. What is the best way to go about this?

EDIT: I also have access to the server but do not have DBA permissions. I can only query the data.

Comment: Do you have login access to the server where the database resides?  Do you have DBA access?

Comment: @MarkStewart Please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the server, use SQLPlus running on the server to invoke your query; that will eliminate the network delay.  To get somewhat precise timings, invoke these SQL*Plus commands first:

```
set timing on
set autotrace on statistics
```

Invoke the SQL a few times; the first time will likely cache the data and subsequent runs will reflect that.  Then do the same queries via your client.

If you had DBA access you could turn on tracing for a session and see exactly how much time is used for each part of the query.